# Merge [batteries] and [cell-battery] tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

[cell-battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-battery) appears on 285 questions but has no tag wiki. [batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries) also appears on 138 of those questions and its tag wiki indicates that its use is for "one or more electrochemical cells", so it seems to me that [cell-battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-battery) should be merged with [batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries) (with the latter as the master tag).

Any objections to this? If there's a reason not to merge them then we should provide a tag wiki for [cell-battery](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-battery).

Comment: There is also battery-charging and charging (i'll bet few to none are about capacitor charging)

Comment: @VoltageSpike Yeah, I've got a list of tags to merge or define usage. I'm just going to go through them one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one has objected, I've merged "cell-battery" into [batteries](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batteries).